# Give a basic page a different appereance by rendering it with views

Tags: theming

I'd like to render a basic page to look somewhat different for my mobile site.
Now I have come up with a combination of `views-view--mobile-aboriginalartsfestival.tpl.php`, `page--mobile-aboriginalartsfestival.tpl.php` & `html--mobile-aboriginalartsfestival.tpl.php` to change the appareance of my `mobile-aboriginalartsfestival` view. Now, the page contains certain elements that I would like to alter, in particular I would like to get rid of the `<h2>` title on top of the content (but not all h2 elements on the page!) and I would like to replace the image, too. How do I best go about it?

**edit 1**

So far, I have a  couple of arrays on top of my page. One contains strings to search for `$searchstr` and the other one `$contentstr`contains strings to replace the search strings with. Then, where to content gets rendered in my `page--mobile-aboriginalartsfestival.tpl.php`, I implemented a few lines like:

```
        <?php $i = 0;
              $contentstr = render($page['content']);

              foreach ($searchstr as &$value) {
                $contentstr = str_replace($value,$replacestr[$i],$contentstr);
                $i++;
                }
              print $contentstr;
        ?>
```

and even thought, that approach seems to work fine, I doubt that it's the best way to go about it, does any one have a better idea for this?

Comment: Did you consider using media queries to achieve what you are after? You can probably get the result that you want with 15 lines of css (and without having to execute php code that can be a pain performance-wise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[Theme Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)** module enabled me, to do what I was looking for: enable a different theme per page based on certain criteria (like mobile browser e.g.).